# Boolean Assert in ABAP Unit

Tags: unit-testing, abap

How do I write a simple ABAP Unit Assert statement to check if any call, expression or other statement evaluates to true?

I can't see any basic `assert()` or `assert_true()` methods in `CL_AUNIT_ASSERT` while I'd expect those to be very common. I can approximate such an assert as follows, but is there no cleaner way?

```
cl_aunit_assert=>assert_equals(
  act = boolc( lv_value > 100 OR lv_value < 2 )
  exp = abap_true ).

cl_aunit_assert=>assert_equals(
  act = mo_model->is_active )
  exp = abap_true ).
```

Comment: Hmmm, maybe it is because there is no boolean type in ABAP?

Comment: I have just got an epiphany. There is no boolean type, but you could simply use `ASSERT_INITIAL` or `ASSERT_NOT_INITIAL` in this case as boolean is emulated by either `X` (true) or space (false). The latter is an initial value in ABAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your SAP NetWeaver stack you can (or should) use the updated ABAP Unit Class `CL_ABAP_UNIT_ASSERT`. This class is available at a Basis-Release >= 7.02. SAP declared this class as 'FINAL' so it´s impossible to inherit from it, but on the other side they added some ASSERT-Methods like the `ASSERT_TRUE` Method!

Here is a possible usage of this method:

```
cl_abap_unit_assert=>assert_true(
  exporting
    act = m_ref_foo->is_bar( l_some_var )
    msg = 'is_bar Method fails with Input { l_some_var }'
).
```

Comment: Please consider reformatting your answer via the Edit link

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about that one. I hope the `FINAL` flag is just an oversight - removing that flag would make migration a lot easier.

Comment: "*SAP declared this class as FINAL*" Of course they did... Looks like others [commented on that as well](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3173204) Bizarrely, there doesn't appear to be any online documentation of the ASSERT_TRUE being added. All I've found is an outdated method list for the 7.0 release. But I've checked the class on a 7.40 system and confirmed that the method is there (though the class documentation is outdated here as well) and this is now the closest standard solution for my original question so I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Well… classes that are final should be declared… final. This class has only static methods which means that it is not designed for inheriting. So good design decision of SAP. No static imports like in Java? Well… maybe in the next 20 years something will be done in this way in ABAP. :)

Answer (score 2):

For the releases I have access to, there's probably no shorter way than the one you outlined. You can create a subclass of `CL_AUNIT_ASSERT` and add your own static `ASSERT_TRUE` method. It's not a bad idea to do so and at the same time make your local ABAP Unit test class a subclass of that `ZCL_AUNIT_ASSERT` - this way, you can omit the `cl_aunit_assert=>` prefix which will save some keystrokes.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot see such methods because there is no boolean type in ABAP.

While in Java, C++ or C, you are able to assign a result of a condition to a variable, like this

```
int i = 5;
boolean result = i > 3;
```

You cannot do the same thing in ABAP as there is no boolean type. Therefore what in other languages is a one liner, in ABAP it will always be more prolix.

```
DATA: i TYPE i VALUE 5.
DATA: result TYPE abap_bool.

IF i > 3.
  result = abap_true.
ELSE.
  result = abap_false.
ENDIF.
```

The thing you used seems to be a new feature, that has been recently added to the language and most of the customers will not be using for a long time. Also the `CL_AUNIT_ASSERT` class was created way before the new elements came to the language.

So right now, there is a possibility to write the above thing as one liner. However there is still no boolean type in the language.

```
DATA: i TYPE i VALUE 5.
DATA: result TYPE abap_bool.

result = boolc( i > 3 ).
```

On the other hand, there is no boolean type, but you could simply use `ASSERT_INITIAL` or `ASSERT_NOT_INITIAL` in this case, as boolean is emulated by either `X` (true) or space (false). The latter is an initial value in ABAP.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way is to just fail:

```
if value > limit. 
  cl_abap_unit_assert=>fail( ). 
endif.
```

Or a more informative:
`cl_abap_unit=>fail( msg = 'Limit exceeded' ).`